# Second order linear differential equation (Cosmolog: Evolution of matter perturbation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to understand the solution obtained for a linear second-order ODE. I am not getting the direct solution given in the text that I am following. The equation is,
[image]

The solution of the above equation is given as,
[image]

Here, an overhead dot represents derivative with respect to $t$ and $a=a(t)$. The connection between $a$ and $t$ is given by Hubble parameter,

$$H(t)=\frac{1}{a} \frac{da}{dt}$$. Other symbols are all constants.One there condition that exists is that $|\Delta| << 1$. I do not know if this condition has anything to do with the given solution but I was not able to exploit the use of this condition.

I have tried to solve it using reduction of order but I get stuck that I am not assuming a functional form of $\Delta$.

Comment: Can you more clearly describe what $\dot a$ is? I read your description as that it is $\frac{da}{da}$ which should be $1$. And is $\frac{d^2Δ}{dt^2}$ to be understood in the sense of the chain rule for $Δ(a(t))$, that is, $\frac{d^2Δ}{dt^2}=\ddotΔ(a(t))a'(t)^2+\dotΔ(a(t))a''(t)$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. it is $\frac{da}{dt}$.

Comment: Also, on your second comment, you are right that a chain rule is to be utilized to the solution.